# Same variable from multiple XML

Tags: php, xml, variables

```
$var1 = new SimpleXMLElement('CSVXML/xvar.xml', null, true);
$var2 = new SimpleXMLElement('CSVXML/yvar.xml', null, true);
```

let's say I get variables from two diffrents XML files, in the first XML files

```
<Number>3698</Number>
<InternalNumber>1</InternalNumber>
<Name>Bob</Name>
<Number>3500</Number>
<InternalNumber>2</InternalNumber>
<Name>Mike</Name>
<Number>2775</Number>
<InternalNumber>3</InternalNumber>
<Name>Dan</Name>
```

in the second XML I get the followings

```
<player>3698</player>
<group>A</group>
```

I do this

```
$varID = $var1->Number;
$varnumber = $var2->player;

if ($varID == $varnumber ){
    echo '$var1->InternalNumber';
}
```

is this possible ?

I simply want to put out a variable, is A for XML! = B from XML2, is there anyway possible to do that?

Comment: "I do this". So, what happens when you do that? Does it work? Errors?

Comment: $var1 is getting wrong, InternalNumber always gives me 1, even if I change my varID

Comment: Are you missing the for loop? That's why you are getting the first result I.e internal number 1 of 3698 everytime. `print_r($var1)` and check the array.

Answer (score 0):

I found this working fine. tested [link](https://eval.in/748274)

```
<?php
$str = <<<XML
<items>
<item>
<Number>3698</Number>
<InternalNumber>1</InternalNumber>
<Name>Bob</Name>
</item>
<item>
<Number>3500</Number>
<InternalNumber>2</InternalNumber >
<Name>Mike</Name>
</item>
<item>
<Number>2775</Number>
<InternalNumber>3</InternalNumber>
<Name>Dan</Name>
</item>
</items>
XML;

$str2 = <<<XML
<item>
<player>3698</player>
<group>A</group>
</item>
XML;

$da = new SimpleXMLElement($str2);
$varnumber = $da->player; 

$data = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
foreach ($data->item as $item)
{

   $this_number = $item->Number;
   //echo $this_number."-".$item->InternalNumber."-".$varnumber."\n";
   if((int)$this_number == (int)$varnumber ){
   $this_internalnumber = $item->InternalNumber;
    echo $this_internalnumber."\n";
     }
     else{
     echo "No Match found \n";
     }
 }
```

Hope this helps.